# Align Objects Evenly

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a project where I have to first randomly create shapes on the frame. Meaning to say, the shape will be at random location.Each created shape would be then stored into a list of array. After that, I will rearrange the shapes position by manipulating the x-axis.

**Assuming following situation:**

5 shapes are created in a panel with both width and height of 200.
Before Alignment, position of each shape is as follow:

- Shape A: x = 40, y = 70
- Shape B: x = 60, y = 50
- Shape C: x = 80, y = 40
- Shape D: x = 20, y = 60
- Shape E: x = 60, y = 20

All these 5 shapes will be then stored into **Shape s**.

Please take note that, I'm re-adjusting the position of x-axis only. The Y- axis will be constant.

**Implementation:**

Now, we initialize the new starting position to be 0;
There is 1 variable;spaces which is determined by width/numberofshapes.
Given width = 200; and 5 shapes created. Therefore spaces is 40.
The spaces is used to determine the gap between the shapes.

So my problem is, it didn't work the way I wish it to be.
Below are both my illustration and code implementation.

**Original Code**

```
else if(command.equals("Align")){
    int currentPosition = 0;
    int spaces = 500 / shapes.size();
    for (Shape s : shapes) {
        s.setX(currentPosition);
        currentPosition = s.getX() + spaces;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

**Revised Code - Implement Sorting**

```
else if(command.equals("Align")){
        int currentPosition = 0;
        int spaces = 500 / shapes.size();

        ArrayList<Shape> sortedShapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        sortedShapes.addAll(shapes);
        Collections.sort(sortedShapes, new Comparator<Shape>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Shape object1, final Shape object2) {
                            return object1.getX() < object2.getX() ? -1 : object1.getX() == object2.getX() ? 0 : 1;
                        }
                    });
        for (Shape s : sortedShapes) {
             s.setX(currentPosition);
             currentPosition = s.getX() + spaces;
        }
        repaint();
}
```

**Images illustration:**

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

---

I'm facing current problem which is shown below:

Before:

[image]

After:

As you can see after i implemented the alignment code, all the shapes is moving towards right and one of it is actually out of border. Which isn't what I wanted.

[image]

Comment: So what is wrong with the result? The image looks just like what I would expect after your description.

Comment: @JensSchauder, I updated the post with images that is showing my current existing problem.

Comment: That's weird, because you set currentPosition (which is 0) to the first Shape, so at least one shape should be at 0 x. I recommend you to print the value of currentPosition on each loop, before changing it.

Comment: Are you sure you are posting your actual code? Please print out currentPosition in the loop and let us know what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sort your shapes first, so the first shape is the lefmost one, and the last shape the rightmost one. This should work:

```
if(command.equals("Align")){
        int currentPosition = 0;
        int spaces = 500 / shapes.size();

        List<Shape> sortedShapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        sortedShapes.addAll(shapes);
        Collections.sort(sortedShapes, new Comparator<Shape>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final Shape object1, final Shape object2) {
                return object1.getX() < object2.getX() ? -1 : object1.getX() == object2.getX() ? 0 : 1;
            }
        });

        for (Shape s : sortedShapes) {
            s.setX(currentPosition);
            currentPosition = s.getX() + spaces;
        }
        repaint();
    }
```

Comment: Arh.. I almost forget about sorting the list out, But, now the object isn't moving.

Comment: Could it be my setX method?
`public void setX(int currentPosition) {
  moveTo(currentPosition,0);
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }`

Comment: IIRC, your moveTo incremented the position. it would be better to change its absolute position, with getX()